# Why is this hanging?

Tags: c#

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var cookie = webBrowser1.Document.Cookie;
        await
            Task.WhenAll(
                listBox1
                .Items
                .Cast<string>()
                .Select(async s =>
                {
                    var data = "action=relationship&user_id=" + s + "&relation=follow";
                    var req = WebRequest.Create("http://example.com") as HttpWebRequest;
                    req.Method = "POST";
                    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                    req.ContentLength = data.Length;
                    req.Headers["cookie"] = cookie;
                    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(await req.GetRequestStreamAsync(), Encoding.ASCII))
                    {
                        sw.Write(data);
                        sw.Close();
                    }
                }));
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
    }
```

I've tried this a million times, and it runs it two times every time. And when it runs it those two times, it does what it's supposed to.

What it's supposed to do is take items from a listbox, and use each item as part of a POST request. Then when it's done, it clears the listbox.

Can someone explain what's wrong?

Comment: You need to URL-encode `s`.

Comment: s is simply a number. So there's no need for URL encoding, but thank you.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: It runs perfectly for two items in the listbox, but after that, it hangs and doesn't run anymore items.

Comment: If you use `WebClient` it has async methods on it which make this easier.

Comment: The question does not include that hanging bug you mentioned. Please modify the question and elaborate a bit on that. For instance by checking where it hangs.

Comment: See my answer, you need to call .GetResponse[Async]() and most importantly .Dispose() the response afterwards

Answer (score 1):

You should call `req.GetResponseAsync()` to actually send the request.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @SLaks

We had the same problem and it turned out to be a problem in different place than one would originally guess.

**You need to .Dispose()** or at least .Close() the **response** that you get from .GetResponseAsync, otherwise the next call to .GetRequestStreamAsync hangs.

It seems that the code behind this holds some limited (rather low) amount of sockets or locks, that disallow further requests to even begin until previous request has completed.